# Create subversion repository on Arch Linux

Tags: apache, svn, archlinux

I'm trying to create a subversion repo in Arch Linux from scratch as following this tutorial in Arch forums :  [Subversion in Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Subversion_Setup#Apache_Subversion_Setup) but it doesn't matter which protocol I use to connect I cannot make it work.

If I try the WebDav authentication as the first part of the wiki and also, checking this other tutorial to complement the info: 
[Tutorial 2](https://minisaha.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/how-to-install-subversion-on-linux-and-make-it-working/) , I get the next message if I try to import a project, locally or even remote i get the same:

```
svn import -m 'I' svn-import/ http://localhost/svn/prueba
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svn/prueba'

svn: E175002: Additional errors:
svn: E175002: PROPFIND request on '/svn/prueba' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

For this one I followed all the steps in Arch wiki and tried putting the `<Location>` configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` or also tried in `/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf` but without results.

In the other hand I tried svnserve as to use the svn protocol but I get an error on the permissions for the format file in my repo file, says permission denied.
For this one, initially I created a user `svn` for subversion and a group `svnusers` to get me and apache(http) user there, with permissions 764 or even 774 in the repo root and beyond, so http could write there but there was no use. Tried then to get http own the directory but same result. I configured the `/etc/conf.d/svnserve` file to get the server work with my repo path at start if your asking and tried also the `svnserve -d -r /path` way but nothing.

Something important to say is as per this other two: [Ubuntu subversion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) and [CentOs subversion](http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-up-svn) (obviously omitting OS specific commands) I set up the `passwd` and the `svnserve.conf` files as needed to use svn protocol or well, svn+ssh but nothing have worked so far.

Could someone tell me the correct way of setting this up and importing a project to it?
My guess is I'm also doing something wrong in issuing the svn import command but don't know what. Thanks

Comment: Update1.- I had an error in the httpd-vhosts.conf as using <Location> conf outside a virtualhost. I fixed it and when importing now my user password is asked at least, but then I get this error: Unexpected HTTP status 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/repos/prueba'

svn: E000002: Additional errors:
svn: E000002: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Comment: Update2.-Corrected the url, it was that why I got the error 500 but as this post opened I'd like to know how to set up the server with svn protocol

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) instead of those resources you refer to. As far as I can tell, they simply got you confused. I make this assumption because you try to configure Apache HTTP Server to expose your repos via HTTP(S) and then you switch to `svnserve`.

Read these SVNBook chapters carefully:

- [SVNBook | Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing),
- [SVNBook | svnserve, a Custom Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve),
- [SVNBook | httpd, the Apache HTTP Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).

Comment: actually I was trying to configure it with svn and then switched to http without ssl and I read at least chapter 6 of the svn but there are OS specific commands and things as to check some tutorials but thanks, I'll read it deeper.